# Why this integer number don't format as a well behaved number?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm in *Android Studio 3.4.2*. I have generated a dummy *Kotlin* code that produces an weird format behaviour. This part was placed soon after `onCreate` start. It's a pure *integer* number!

```
fmtFloat = DecimalFormat("#,###.##############")   
fmtFloat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING)
Log.d("myMess", fmtFloat.format("98765432".toDouble()))
```

The `logCat` image is

[image: LogCat]

When I run this expression in the evaluate expression window, the same problem:

[image: Evaluate Window]

However, when I run the SAME code as a desktop test in *Android Studio* there is no error.

```
98.765.432
```

In [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org) also works correctly.

Why in *Android* app it happens and in Desktop it's different?

Wheb debugging the Android app, I execute in evaluate windows:

```
"98765432".toDouble()==98765432.0
```

It's `true`!

**UPDATE**
When one uses the default rounding mode (HALF_EVEN) for *Decimal Format*, it's working also in my Android App. It accepts until 14 digits (that I've choose for safety) before display the number in exponential format. So the mystery goes on...

**UPDATE 2**
My number that enters in format method in a `Decimal Format` variable is a `Double`, that has [64 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) with 53 bits for mantissa. It stores whole numbers until 16 digits and my number has just  8 digits!
[image: Java number]

Comment: I know it, but the binary representation for an integer number is exact and it does not explain why the same format commands works different in Android and Desktop. The binary representation of Double is the same in both platforms.   Also it does not explain why `HALF_EVEN` rounding mode solves the problem for Android.

Comment: A floating point for an integer is only exact IF it fits into the mantissa.  That's not the case here.

Comment: Note that the original value is a float.  That's then expanded into a double.  A float only has 24 bits of mantissa, with a maximum value of 16,777,216.  So the original float was rounded, leading to a rounded double

Comment: The accuracy of the mantissa is considered to reach 15 to 17 decimal places (53 bits for the mantissa). I'm talking about `Double` numbers, which occupy 8 bytes or 64 bits. The example in question has much less. It's only 8 digits! For whole numbers, this ranges up to 9,007,199,254,740,989 (2^53 -1). Read  here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: The format name variable is `fmtFloat`, but it's just a name. The number is a double!

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Comment: Here is the official details about Double Java type.

Comment: That's for a double.  Something here is passing it through a float, which has 24 bits.

Comment: `fmtFloat = DecimalFormat("#,###.##############")` is just a format spec. The number that enter in  `fmtFloat.format` call is a double `"98765432".toDouble()` Where you are seeing a floating number? Please, see the first image in the question.